# Uncaught ReferenceError: Messages is not defined meteor chat tutorial

Tags: javascript, meteor, referenceerror

I am following [this](http://vimeo.com/40300075) meteor chat tutorial and I am halfway, the teacher finishes a piece of code and checks it out in the console in the browser and says good "no errors" but I am getting a error a the same point. Any help as to why I am getting this error would be great.

file.js

```
Message = new Meteor.Collection('messages');

if (Meteor.is_client){
  Template.messages.messages = function () {
    return Messages.find({}, { sort: {time: -1} });
  };
}
```

file.html

```
<head>
  <title>tutorial</title>
</head>

<body>
 {{> entry}}

 {{> messages}}
</body>

<template name="entry">
    <p>
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="your name">
    <input type="text" id="messageBox" placeholder="your message"></p>
</template>

<template name="messages">
    {{#each messages}}
        {{> message}} <!--echo of message template-->
    {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="message">
    <p><strong>{{name}}:</strong>{{message}}</p>
</template>
```

Error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Messages is not defined
```

**UPDATE**

Doing the following message = return ... gives me the output below

```
Your app is crashing. Here's the latest log.


app/tutorial.js:5
     message = return Messages.find({}, { sort: {time: -1} });
               ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token return
    at /Users/anderskitson/Sites/tutorial/.meteor/local/build/server/server.js:113:21
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/usr/local/meteor/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    at run (/Users/anderskitson/Sites/tutorial/.meteor/local/build/server/server.js:99:7)
Exited with code: 1
Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

Comment: `Message = ...` `return Messages.find`

Comment: @nneonneo I added a update to what happened when I used your code.

Comment: Uh, no, I was pointing out the mismatch between you declaring `Message` and returning `Message` **s** `.find`.

Comment: @nneonneo could you possibly refactor my code as a answer and show me what you mean. I dont quite get it.

Comment: I just did...please refresh the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
Message = new Meteor.Collection('messages');
```

declares a variable called `Message`. So, later on, you can use the variable `Message`.

This line:

```
return Messages.find({}, { sort: {time: -1} });
```

uses the variable `Message`**s**, which is not defined! Only `Message` is defined. So, write

```
return Message.find({}, { sort: {time: -1} });
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check Meteor.isClient before

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {  
  alert(); 
}
```